# To avoid bal tashchis, halachically, should people limit the quantity of "junk food" in mishloach manot?

Tags: halacha, purim, mishloach-manot, bal-tashchit-waste

Each year, after Purim, I am left with mounds of candy bars, wafers, juice boxes and other junk food that no one in my family eats. It gets thrown into the garbage. Seriously, we tried one year giving this to another family that has a lot of kids, and the parents took it not to embarrass us. But, afterwards, the mom asked us not to do this again as it was not healthy for her kids.

No doubt, many people have this experience - the junk food gets thrown out. So, halachically, to avoid wasted food, should people either not include "junk food" at all, or limit sending mishloach manot to just one person, perhaps? Any other trick to avoid *bal taschis*?

Comment: Don't give too much, I just gave a bottle of 0.5 coca cola and an apple :)

Comment: @havarka Exactly. You should save your money to give to poor people. No one actually needs all that candy at all, whereas poor peopled don't have food at all.

Comment: And, candy doesn't really fulfill the mitzvah - the mitzvah is food that would be part of the Purim Seudah, and as much as you *could* eat candy at the meal, it's not really a meal food.

Comment: @YeZ - agreed, but I'll throw in something. I believe that there are many leniences regarding the Se'udah restriction. Seems it just has to be readily edible, and candy is that. Other arg. could be made that the Se'udah extends to the family & not just the recipient. Many kids make candy their meal. (Not saying this is healthy, but this happens quite a bit.)

Comment: @DanF candy doesn't become a meal even if you want it to. And I'd like you to cite some of these leniencies.